# How to display something if user has firstname and something else if he hasn't

Tags: php, wordpress

My code for now is the following:

```php
function show_loggedin_function( $atts ) {
    global $current_user, $user_login;
        get_currentuserinfo();
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
    if ($user_login) 
        return 'Bienvenue <br>' . $current_user->user_firstname . ' !';
    else
        return '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . ' ">Login</a>'; 
}
```

I want to add a condition if user is logged in and if he has user name like :

```
if ($user_login && user_firstname = true) return B
else ($user_login && user_firstname = false) return A
else return ...
```

Is it the correct formulation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are looking for is:

```php
if ($user_login) {
    if (isset($current_user->user_firstname)) {
       // User logged in and first name set
       return B;
    }

    // User logged in and first name not set
    return A;
}

// User not logged in
return C;
```

So this checks if user is logged in and the user has first name set. Than the code inside the if-statement will be executed.

If the requirements are met, the code below the if-statement will not be executed. So you don't need a separate else-statement here. If the if-statement not is true, then the code below it will be executed and returned.

Comment: Thanks!But what If I want to return A, B, C ?

Comment: @Clément I've updated the code in my answer and also added some comments with explanation.

Comment: If this is helpful, please feel free to accept / upvote answer for future visitors.

Comment: I've tried and receive an error for all website : function show_loggedin_function( $atts ) {

 global $current_user, $user_login;
       get_currentuserinfo();
 add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
 if ($user_login) isset($current_user->user_firstname) {
  return 'Bienvenue <br>' . $current_user->user_firstname . ' !'; //B
 }
return 'Bienvenue !'; } //A
 
return '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . ' ">Login</a>'; //C
 
}
add_shortcode( 'show_loggedin_as', 'show_loggedin_function' );

Comment: O, if-statement around isset() was missing. I've updatet the code in my answer. Can you check if this works? Comments can also be removed in the code.

Comment: It's seems that the choice A isn't return but B and C yes

Comment: A should be returned if `$current_user->user_firstname` doesn't exist at all. Is that also your case? Or also if this value is `null` or `''`? In that case should be better to use `if (!empty($current_user->user_firstname))` instead.